# Ввод нескольких тестов построчно

Tags: python

Входные данные содержат одно или несколько тестовых заданий. В каждой строке содержится по одному тестовому заданию.
Каждая строка содержит день название месяца  и год
Количество тестовых заданий не превышает 100000

Ввод:

```
1 January 2020
31 December 2022
```

Вывод

```
Wednesday
Saturday
```

Саму задачу я сделал, но как сделать ввод нескольких значений не знаю.
Если делаю так:

```
import datetime
data = []
while True:
    text = input()
    if not text:
        break
    day, m, year = text.split()
    day = int(day)
    year = int(year)
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(m, "%B")
...
```

то Яндекс контест выводит ошибку EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: я уверен, что про циклы вам уже рассказывали

Comment: Если делаю так:
`import datetime
data = []
while True:
    text = input()
    if not text:
        break
    day, m, year = text.split()
    day = int(day)
    year = int(year)`
то Яндекс контест выводит ошибку
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Добавляйте код в тело вопроса, вы можете редактировать вопрос. В комментариях код совершенно не читабелен по жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сначала записать все вводимые данные в лист

```
input_data = []
while True:
    text = input()
    if not text:
        break
    input_data.append(text)
```

а потом уже их обработать (вне первого цикла `while`):

```
for e in input_data:
    # обработка:
    day, m, year = e.split()
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

слегка подправил ваш код, теперь он работает:

```
import datetime

while True:
    text = input()
    if not text:
        break
    w = datetime.datetime.strptime(text, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%A')
    print(w)
```

ввод-вывод:

```
1 January 2020
Wednesday
31 December 2022
Saturday
```

Answer (score -1):

Ввести получилось только через файл:

```
import datetime

ifile = open("input.txt", "r")
dates = [line.rstrip() for line in ifile.readlines()]
for date in dates:
    day, m, year = date.split()
    day = int(day)
    year = int(year)
    # ...
```